# Search from my site in different site

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I Want to make my form to Search in different site *(different site:example.com)*
The Search word (xxx) need to direct to:
http://www.example.com/search___XXX.html

A friend wrote me this function:

```
function SearchKeyword()
{

var searchKeyword="";

            if($('.txtSearch').eq(0).val() !="Search")   //mobile
                            searchKeyword = trim( $('.txtSearch').eq(0).val() );

            if($('.txtSearch').eq(1).val() !="Search")   
                            searchKeyword = trim( $('.txtSearch').eq(1).val() );                           


 //  searchKeyword = trim($('#txtSearch').val());
if(searchKeyword != ""){        
    document.location.href = 'search___' + searchKeyword + '.html';
}
}
```

How to Connect it With this Html Form ?

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
 </button>
```

I think That my friend didn't connect the code to the site and this JS is generally

Thanks for any help !
John

Answer (score 1):

You need to change class of your input element, from `"searchTerm"` to `"txtSearch"`.
Or change all `'txtSearch'` in function to `'searchTerm'`.

Comment: Not working yet, need to connect the function to the site , but how ?

Comment: What you mean by 'connect function to the site' ? You mean add script to the page? To add it, put function between `'<script></script>'` tags just before `'</body>'` tag.

Comment: No . i want to search in different site.
 (different site:example.com) The Search word (xxx) need to direct to: http://www.example.com/search___XXX.html

its not on the script